# How can I remove repetitive code in swift?

Tags: swift

I have 2 sections and 6 lines of code that do the opposite things for an app that I have made for a project.  The code was typed as it was taught to us, but in the project review I was told to get rid of the repetitive/like code.  Can anyone help point me in the right direction with this?  Thanks

```
 @IBAction func stopRecording(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        recordButton.isEnabled = true
        stopRecordingButton.isEnabled = false
        recordingLabel.text = "Tap to Record"
   }


 @IBAction func recordAudio(_ sender: AnyObject)
        {
            recordingLabel.text = "Recording in Progress"
            stopRecordingButton.isEnabled = true
            recordButton.isEnabled = false
      }
```

Comment: Have you solved your problem?

Answer (score 2):

You can also do this by `didSet` Observer.

```
var isRecording: Bool = false {
    didSet {
        recordButton.isEnabled = !isRecording
        stopRecordingButton.isEnabled = isRecording
        recordingLabel.text = isRecording ? "Recording in progress" : "Tap to Record"
    }
}
```

And the actions become pretty simple like this.

```
@IBAction func stopRecording(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    isRecording = false
}


@IBAction func recordAudio(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    isRecording = true
}
```

Comment: Love this answer.